# Define two rational numbers $\alpha$ and $x$ such that $\sin( { \alpha }) =x$

Tags: trigonometry, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Of course for $x\neq 0 $ and $\alpha$ in radians. Can you define them?

Comment: Sine is transcendental. Any rational input would get your an irrational number.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao, wrong. $\sin 0 = 0$.

Comment: @vonbrand Ok, you are right, except for the input $0$, :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the Lindenmann-Weierstrass theorem is an overkill for this problem. Ivan Niven got an elementary proof of

> For any rational $r\neq 0$, $\cos r$ is irrational.

in his book *Irrational Numbers* by exploiting the fact that rational number being the roots of a polynomial, the proof is not lengthy, and is very inspiring, I learned the proof back in college days. Here I just copy the proof (thus making the answer a community wiki) and adapt it for sine function:

> Claim: For any rational $r\neq 0$, $\sin r$ is irrational.

For a positive $r = a/b$, where $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}^+$. For $p$ being an odd prime to be specified, define
$$
f(x) = \frac{x^{p-1}(a-bx)^{2p}(2a-bx)^{p-1}}{(p-1)!} = \frac{(r-x)^{2p}\big(r^2 - (r-x)^2\big)^{p-1}b^{3p-1}}{(p-1)!}\tag{1}
$$
For $0<x<r$:
$$
0<f(x)< \frac{r^{2p}(r^2)^{p-1}b^{3p-1}}{(p-1)!} = \frac{r^{4p-2}b^{3p-1}}{(p-1)!} \tag{2}
$$
Next, define $F(x)$ using all the even derivatives of $f(x)$
$$
F(x) = f(x) - f''(x) + f^{(4)}(x) - f^{(6)}(x) + \cdots - f^{(4p-2)}(x).
$$
Thus
$$
\big(F'(x)\cos x + F(x)\sin x\big)' = F''(x)\cos x + F(x)\cos x = f(x)\cos x
$$
and
$$
\int^r_0 f(x)\cos x \,dx = F'(r)\cos r + F(r)\sin r + F(0). \tag{3}
$$
Next, what Ivan Niven does is proving $F'(r)=0$ by construction to get rid of $\cos$, computing $F(r)$ and $F(0)$, setting $\sin r$ to be rational, then to get a contradiction.

- $F'(r)=0$ follows from $f(x)$ has a factor of $(r-x)^2$.
- For $f(x)$ has form $x^{p-1}g(x)/(p-1)!$, $g(x)$ has all integer coefficients, $f^{(j)}(0)$ is an integer, also notice $f^{(j)}(0)$ is a multiple of $p$ unless $j=p-1$. Direct computation from (1) gives
  $$
  f^{(p-1)}(0) = a^{2p}(2a)^{p-1}.
  $$
  If $p>a$, and $p$ is an odd prime, then $f^{(p-1)}(0)$ is not divisible by $p$. Thus $F(0) = q$, where $q$ and $p$ are relatively prime.
- The definition (1) implies that
  $$
  f(r-x) = \frac{x^{2p}(a^2 - b^2x^2)^{p-1}b^{p+1}}{(p-1)!}.
  $$
  Using similar argument as above, $f^{(j)}(r)$ is a multiple of $p$. Hence let $F(r) = pm$ for some integer $m$.

Now assume

> $\sin r = d/k$ is rational for $d,k\in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

It suffices to show for positive sine value for $\sin(\cdot)$ is an odd function. Plugging all above results into (3):
$$
k\int^r_0 f(x)\cos x \,dx = pmd + kq\tag{4}
$$
The contradiction will be obtained by choosing $p$:

> Choose $p$ large enough such that the right side of (4) is a non-zero integer, and left side is strictly in $(-1,1)$.

For $p>a$ is already required, now let $p>k$, thus $p$ is relatively prime with $kq$, thus right side of (4) is a non-zero integer. Now by (2):
$$
\left|k\int^r_0 f(x)\cos x \,dx\right| < kr^3b^2\frac{(r^4b^3)^{p-1}}{(p-1)!}
$$
Since
$$
\lim_{p\to \infty} \frac{(r^4b^3)^{p-1}}{(p-1)!} = 0
$$
So we can choose $p$ large enough so that the left side of (4) is strictly in $(-1,1)$. Contradiction, hence the claim holds.

---

Notice Ivan Niven's proof tells us nothing about whether $\sin r$ can be algebraic. For that part I believe we have to borrow the Lindenmann-Weierstrass theorem, if I am wrong here someone please point out.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Yes, I posted the adapted version.

Answer (score 6):

When $\alpha$ is rational and nonzero, $\sin \alpha$ is transcendental. This follows from the [Lindenmann-Weierstrass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) theorem.