# Constructive proof of the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$.

Tags: irrational-numbers, constructive-mathematics, rationality-testing

The fact that there exists irrational number $a,b$ such that $a^b$ is rational is proved by the law of excluded middle, but I read somewhere that irrationality of $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ is proved constructively. Do you know the proof?

Comment: See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem).

Comment: @DavidMitra: many thanks, I was not aware of that theorem.

Comment: One can find this result, and its proof, in [Ivan Niven's book *Irrational numbers*](http://books.google.com/books/about/Irrational_Numbers.html?id=ov-IlIEo47cC).

Comment: @Potato: you can retract your vote.

Comment: Interesting question! Just about all proofs of transcendence I'm aware of essentially assume the target is algebraic and conclude that there is an integer strictly between $0$ and $1$. Not sure whether anything like this can be turned into a constructively (or intuitionistically) valid argument. I am also not aware of any proof of irrationality of $\sqrt2^{\sqrt2}$ other than the transcendence proof of Gelfond-Schneider. (Of course, I'm probably just overlooking something.)

Comment: @Avatar I haven't noticed that feature before! Thanks.

Comment: @Potato: It's a brand new feature.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Wonderful.

Comment: Since the answers so far seem to miss the difficulty, let me make here some general remarks: A constructive proof of the Gelfond-Schneider result for $x=\sqrt 2^\sqrt2$ *cannot* begin by assuming that $x$ is algebraic, hoping to derive a contradiction. If we tried to follow this outline, we would have to begin with the assumption that $x$ is *not transcendental*, which without excluded middle is not (necessarily) the same as saying that it is algebraic. But then the proof vanishes, as we cannot use the putative polynomial of $x$ to derive estimates (we do not have a polynomial anymore)!

Comment: @Andres: isn't the definition of "transcendental" just "not algebraic"? Then a constructive proof that a number is transcendental is precisely a proof of a contradiction from the assumption that number is algebraic. I am not very familiar with the actual proof so I can't say much about the details, but see http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2005-March/008846.html

Comment: Yes, Carl, but without excluded middle, "not not algebraic" does not give you "algebraic", does it? (And the OP seems to be requiring to avoid the use of excluded middle.) Anyway, you know this better than I do. Maybe I'm overlooking something. (If this is not an issue, then yes, the bounds in these arguments are obtained effectively.)

Comment: Mark Sapir's [answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/138291/6085) on MathOverflow.

Comment: How could a proof of $\textit{ir}$rationality be constructive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deciding whether $2^{\sqrt2}$ is irrational/transcendental](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173804/deciding-whether-2-sqrt2-is-irrational-transcendental)

Comment: @JackM, it can't be.  [Discussion in chat about it.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39379412#39379412)

Comment: Most mathematicians *don't* usually use the word "constructive" in the sense of mathematical logic.  Rather, they use it to mean "a  proof which leads to an explicit example". For instance, the proof that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational is constructive, whereas the argument that there is an irrational number because there are uncountably many reals but only countably many rationals is non-constructive. Perhaps the OP had the specific logical usage in mind, but it's not obvious -- and indeed, the follow-up question on Mathoverflow doesn't make any reference to mathematical logic.

Answer (score 13):

Since this is a well-established result, this is a community wiki post.

Relevant question: [Deciding whether $2^{\sqrt2}$ is irrational/transcendental](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173804/deciding-whether-2-sqrt2-is-irrational-transcendental)

Kuzmin proved the [following claim](http://mi.mathnet.ru/eng/izv5316) in 1930:

> **Theorem:** If $\alpha\neq 0,1$ is algebraic, $\beta$ is positive and rational, not a perfect square, then $\alpha^{\sqrt{\beta}}$ is transcendental.

Unfortunately the paper is in Russian and I failed to find an English translation. A corollary of this is that $2^{\sqrt{2}}$ is transcendental, and so is its square root $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$.

The outlines of both Gelfond and Kuzmin's constructive proof can be found [here](http://euclid.colorado.edu/~tubbs/courses/Chapter%20Three.pdf).

As David Mitra pointed out the comments, [Niven's book](http://books.google.com/books/about/Irrational_Numbers.html?id=ov-IlIEo47cC) had a section dedicated to this. I *love* Niven's book so much. The technique is similar to the [adapted proof I posted here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386059/define-two-rational-numbers-alpha-and-x-such-that-sin-alpha-x), proof by contradiction.

Rough idea about the construction: First assuming $\alpha^{\sqrt{\beta}}$ is algebraic. Then using sufficient large degree Lagrange interpolation polynomial to approximate $e^{(\ln \alpha)x}$ at points $\{a+ b\sqrt{2}\}$ for $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$. Let the number of points go to infinity   the error will go to zero, this shows a transcendental function $\alpha^x$ can be interpolate using countably many algebraic points. Contradiction.

Comment: Not a constructive argument (in the sense of mathematical logic), though.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Thanks for the heads up, I didn't realize there could be a constructive proof in the sense of mathematical logic. I appreciate if you write one, I want to learn it as well. :)

Comment: I don't know if there is one. It seems a difficult question.

Comment: To all the voters out there: the OP asks whether the irrationality of ${\sqrt 2} ^{\sqrt 2}$ can be proved CONSTRUCTIVELY. I fail to see how this upvoted answer addresses the question.

Comment: @AlexM. This question shows up as the answerable one in a "duplicate of..." chain for a number of questions that were not asking for this requirement. Some of them weren't even asking about $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Why should increasing the number of interpolation points makes the error goes to zero? This is not a general fact of interpolation, right?

Comment: Even if the original proof uses classical logic freely, it should still hopefully form a valid proof in the internal logic of the topos of $\lnot\lnot$-sheaves of an intuitionistic universe.  On the other hand, hopefully the interpretation of the formula $\forall p, q : \mathbb{N}^+, \frac{p}{q} \ne \sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ should end up being the same thing in the intuitionistic universe (where $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ is completely fine as an element of the constructive reals).