# What exactly are those "two irrational numbers" $x$ and $y$ such that $x^y$ is rational?

Tags: exponentiation, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, constructive-mathematics

It's [possible to prove nonconstructively](https://web.archive.org/web/20180129000737/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51618.html) that there exists irrational numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $x^y$ is rational, but that proof only proves that such numbers exist and does not specify what they are.

What is a **constructive** proof that there are two irrational numbers $x$, $y$ such that $x^y$ is rational, i.e. what are those numbers?

Comment: Take $\alpha = \sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$, and $\beta = \sqrt{2}$, and look at $\alpha^{\beta}$

Comment: It is known that $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$ is irrational (transcendental); see this [previous Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446647/irrationality-of-sqrt2-sqrt2).

Comment: If we don't have to use real numbers, then $e^{\pi i} = -1$ is an easy construction (assuming we don't have to prove the irrationality of $e$ and $\pi).$ Reminds me of how easy it is to get a continuous nowhere differentiable function when you get to use complex numbers --- just use $f(z) = |z|.$

Comment: @Kf-Sansoo Thanks for that example; I did not think to consider actually *testing out* $(x,y)=(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}),(\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}},\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: @MiloBrandt Thanks for pointing that out; I would not consider this question a duplicate of that question, but I do admit that the answer to this question is contained within the answers to that question (though notably, this question is not answered in the accepted answer to that question).

Because of this, I'm not sure whether or not to mark it as a duplicate. What do you think?

Comment: @Harry I'm inclined to think that marking as duplicate would be good since the answers here are equivalent to answers already over there (and any answer here would serve as an answer there) as well as that the answers there do serve this sub-question. On the other hand, it's not an exact duplicate, so it's not like closing as duplicate is an obvious, uncontentious choice (and you're certainly free to vote however you wish).

Comment: @hardmath Thanks, that settles the matter.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let $x=3^{1/2}$ and $y=\log_{3}(4)$. Then $x^y=2$.

The proof that $x$ is irrational is familiar. For $y$, suppose $y=p/q$ where $p$ and $q$ are positive integers. Then $3^{p/q}=4$, so $3^p=4^q$. This is impossible, since $4^q$ is even and $3^p$ is odd.

Comment: Thank you. I chose this as the accepted answer because it explains why $x$ and $y$ are irrational.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: I posted a proof that $3^{1/2}$ is irrational here.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4852743/considering-rectangles-whose-perimeter-long-side-ratio-is-equal-to-long-side-sho

Answer (score 17):

Let $x = \mathrm{e}$ and $y = \ln(2)$, then $x^y = \mathrm{e}^{\ln(2)} = 2$.

Comment: It would improve your Answer (which I already upvoted) if you added some details about why $e, \ln 2$ are known to be irrational.

Comment: Explained in my answer here.

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4862041/928654