# Two irrational numbers $a,b$ with $a^{b}\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Are there two irrational numbers $a,b$ such that $a^{b}$ is a natural number?

**Edit:**  After  the  answer of  Lhf we add the  following:

Are there two irrational but algebraic numbers $a,b$   with $a^{b} \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Exactly. There must be by construction. For every irrational $a$ that is not itself an integer to a rational power (so everything except for roots of integers), there is an irrational $b=\log_a n$.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1609918/what-exactly-are-those-two-irrational-numbers-x-and-y-such-that-xy-is-r

Answer (score 9):

$e^{\log n} = n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

It is well known and easy to prove that $e$ is irrational.

If $\log n=a/b$ with $a,b \in \mathbb Z$, then $e^a=n^b$ and $e$ would be algebraic (but it is harder to prove that $e$ is not algebraic).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1609976/589 is easier

Comment: @Ihf  thank you. What about two irrational but algebraic numbers $a,b$?

Comment: @AliTaghavi, perhaps add a separate question?

Answer (score 4):

There exists irrationals $a,b$ such that $a^b$ is rational.

**EXAMPLE**: We know that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational and that $2$ is rational. We also have $q=\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ is irrational by the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Gelfond-Schneider_Theorem).

Consider the expression $(\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}})^{\sqrt{2}}$. This can be written as $(\sqrt{2})^{\sqrt{2}\times \sqrt{2}} = (\sqrt{2})^2 = 2$ which is rational.

Hence, we have $a=\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ and $b=\sqrt{2}$ such that $a^b$ is rational.

---

**EDIT**: You can also see other proofs [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Existence_of_Rational_Powers_of_Irrational_Numbers).

Comment: @MaxPayne Not exactly - the question asks for $a^b$ integer, not just rational.

Comment: Question needs a proof by construction, this is not a proof that there exists two irrational numbers = natural as you'd need to prove that $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$ is irrational

Comment: @Ephemeral That is why I have provided a link to the Gelfond theorem.