# Is the sine of a transcendental angle transcendental or algebraic?

Tags: number-theory

Let $x$ be a transcendental number Algebraically Independent from $\pi$. It is known if $ \sin x $ is also transcendental or algebraic?

For example, is $\sin \sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}\pi$ algebraic or transcendental?

NOTE: Then the sine of an transcendental number is not necessary transcendental. Are there any known example in which $\sin x$ is algebraic for another transcendental number, different of $\pi$ and that is not defined with the use of inverse trigonometric functions?

Comment: @Fakemistake : maybe he meant $\frac{x}{2 \pi}$ is transcendental ? (it seems that $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ is transcendental http://math.stackexchange.com/a/446905/276986 , [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond–Schneider_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond–Schneider_theorem) )

Comment: The are countably many algebraic and uncountably many transcendental numbers. So the statement "sin transcedental is always algebraic" cannot be true. As Fakemistake's example show, "sin transcendental is always transcedental" is also false.

Comment: @achillehui : what about what I wrote ?

Comment: @user1952009 - I don't have an example at hand for your case.  I'll wait until OP clarify what hir mean.

Comment: Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture

Answer (score 4):

$\arcsin(1/3)$ is known to be transcendental, so it is a transcendental number whose sine is algebraic, indeed, rational.

More detail: Let $\arcsin(1/3)=x$, so $\sin x=1/3$ is algebraic (indeed, rational). By the Lindemann-Weierstrass Theorem, if $x$ is a nonzero algebraic number, then $\sin x$ is transcendental (says Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number). Therefore, $x$ is transcendental.

Comment: Downvoters: is my answer not mathematically correct? does it not answer the question? has anyone posted a better answer? do *you* have a better answer? Please, speak up!