# Is $x^x$ rational for $x=\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$

Tags: rational-numbers, constructive-mathematics

This might be naive. Is $x^x$ a rational number for $x=\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$ ?

I remember reading somewhere a long time ago that such $x^x$ is a rational number, as an example of issues with non-constructive math and excluded middle. (I think the question was whether there exists irrational $x$, such that $x^x$ is rational.)  But I didn't give it much thought or figured out why. I dismissed the issue as I **mistakenly** thought exponentiation is associative, and assumed $x^x = \sqrt{2}^2=2$.

Can someone help show constructively whether this is a rational number?

Related:

[Can an irrational number raised to an irrational power be rational?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104119/can-an-irrational-number-raised-to-an-irrational-power-be-rational)

[irrationality of $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446647/irrationality-of-sqrt2-sqrt2)

Comment: When $x$ and $y$ are algebraic numbers then we can use the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) to tell us if $x^y$ is trancendental irrational. When $x$ and $y$ are trancendental it becomes a much harder problem (note that $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ is trancendental by GS). Your number is almost surely irrational (and trancendental), but it might be hard to prove this.

Comment: @Winther: You probably mean "When $x$ and $y$ are **irrational** algebraic", right?