# Is $2^\sqrt{2}$ is rational or irrational?

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

There are many popular problems on irrational power rational. A very interesting read is [this blog](https://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/30002.3-5.shtml%20'this%20blog'). And there are many specific examples where rational power irrational is rational (e.g. $2^{\log_2(3)}$). But what about $2^{\sqrt{2}}$? Is it rational or irrational?

Comment: @N74 Yes, indeed, but also very popular with hundreds of [duplicates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446647/irrationality-of-sqrt2-sqrt2?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem), it is transcendental (and, in particular, irrational).